# Why the txt file can not find in the Android device?

Tags: android, file

I am developing in the Android. I found a sample code. It open the file by the following code:

```
private static final String TEST_DATA_FILE_NAME = "test.txt";
FileInputStream fin = activity.openFileInput(TEST_DATA_FILE_NAME);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
```

and use  `String text = br.readLine();` to read.

I use following code to get the file path:

```
File outFile =activity.getDatabasePath(MESH_DATA_FILE_NAME);
Log.i(TAG, "outFile.getPath() = " + outFile.getPath());
```

And it show the following log:

**`outFile.getPath() = /data/data/com.test.app.test/databases/test.txt`**

I want to get the **test.txt** and send to computer via some file manager App.
But I can not find the **test.txt** , I also can not find the above path.

Why I can not fine the file ?
How to get the **test.txt** file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you find it?  My first guess would be because it isn't there.

Comment: @nasch If it isn't there , why it can get the path like the following:
**`outFile.getPath() = /data/data/com.test.app.test/databases/test.txt`** ?

Comment: I don't think that implies that the file exists. What does a call to `File.exists()` return?

Comment: I think using "activity.getDatabasePath(MESH_DATA_FILE_NAME);" was a wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on the SDcard you can read it

```
            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = "/somefolder/file.txt";
            File myFile = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);

            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";

            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";

            }


            String filecontent = aBuffer;
            myReader.close();
```